# Create-react-app and meta-data

Tags: reactjs, seo, meta-tags, meta, create-react-app

Am on a project that is purely client-facing and i have been using `create-react-app` to kickstart it all and it seems to be working fine.

However, I have been encountering problems with understanding `create-react-app` with seo and I couldn't find any related articles on how the two can go hand in hand.

The project am working on, is currently using `react-router` in terms of routing and `react-document-meta` for inserting of meta-data.

When i inspect the elements of the page in browser and also with Mozbar (the SEO toolbar) , i am able to see the meta-data and title. But it will not showed up in google fetch and render - mostly just script tags.

Isit due to the fact that the meta data are loaded in the individual component-render method, thus google unable to load it? Or it is just google not understanding that the tags are in the component?

Here's a snippet in my one of my component.js

```
const meta = {
    title: 'Testing 123',
    description: "Blah blah blah"
}

return (
    <div>
        <DocumentMeta {...meta} />
        <...elements>
    </div>
)
```

Some articles solutions are to render it on server-rendering. But it seems really complex and I am quite new to react.

Please point me to the right solution or if there's a work around method.

Thank you

Comment: create-react-app does not support server-side rendering, so you will need to add that feature in order to support seo

Comment: @ReiDien so it is the server-side rendering that's causing the issue? do you recommend i eject the create-react-app and build it from there?

Comment: @Ariel I am facing same problem. What solution you came across to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

i'm using react-helmet , link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet . And it's worked very nice on my universal react app, you can check on http://kompetisiindonesia.com and then view source.

Comment: im currently using [react-document-meta](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-document-meta) . Okay will try changing it to react-helmet instead! thank you!